# 19-арная пирамида из бинарной

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть один код, писал с помощью статьи с вики. Вот сам код:

https://ideone.com/IWHTrJ
https://ideone.com/JuoxtN

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H

void heapify(int a[], int i);
void buildHeap(int a[], int size);
void heapIncreaseKey(int a[], int i, int key);
void heapInsert(int a[], int key);
int heapExtractMax(int a[]);

#endif

#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include "heap.h"

int heapSize;

//Восстановление свойства кучи
void heapify(int a[], int i){
    int left = 2*i;
    int right = 2*i + 1;
    //heapSize - количество элементов в куче
    int largest = i;
    if((left <= heapSize) && (a[left] > a[i]))
        largest = left;
    if((right <= heapSize) && (a[right] > a[largest]))
        largest = right;
    if(largest != i){
        std::swap(a[i], a[largest]);
        heapify(a, largest);
    }
}

//перестроение в кучу массива длина size
void buildHeap(int a[], int size){
    heapSize = size;
    for(int i = size/2; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(a, i);
}

//Изменение значения элемента
void heapIncreaseKey(int a[], int i, int key){
    if(key < a[i])
        return; //Ошибка
    a[i] = key;
    while((i > 0) && (a[i/2] < a[i])){
        std::swap(a[i], a[i/2]);
        i = i / 2;
    }
}

//Добавление элемента
void heapInsert(int a[], int key){
    heapSize = heapSize + 1;
    a[heapSize] = -INT_MAX;
    heapIncreaseKey(a, heapSize, key);
}

//Извлечение максимального элемента
int heapExtractMax(int a[]){
    if(heapSize < 0)
        return 0;   //Ошибка: куча пуста
    int max = a[0];
    a[0] = a[heapSize];
    heapSize = heapSize - 1;
    heapify(a, 0);
    return max;
}
```

Вторая часть задания: Реализовать операции перестроения массива в d-арную пирамиду, добавления произвольного элемента и извлечения максимального элемента из d-арной пирамиды, где d = 19. Каким образом это можно сделать в каждой функции?

Comment: "*это можно сделать в каждой функции*" - это не нужно делать в каждой функции. В этом нет никакого смысла вообще. Вам нужно что-то вроде: `Tree & ArrayToTree( Tree & tree, Array & array )`. А теории и кода про n-арные деревья в сети навалом, есть что поразглядывать.

Comment: А я вот что-то ничего хорошего не могу найти по запросам d-арное дерево, преобразование массива в дерево или d-ary tree.

Comment: Преобразовывать массив в дерево, собственно, и не надо :) Просто берёте дерево и добавляете туда элементы массива. Только надо сначала решить что делать с одинаковыми. Ищите не "d-арное дерево", а "n-арное" :)